# Homology of Lens spaces with coefficients in an abelian group, and explicit generators in some cases

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups, projective-space

Consider the $2n+1$ dimensional sphere $S^{2n+1}$ as the submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ defined by
$$
|z_1|^2+...+|z_{n+1}|^2=1 \ .
$$
Given an integer $p$ we consider the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ action on $S^{2n+1}$ whose generator is
$$
z_i\rightarrow e^{\frac{2\pi i }{p}}z_i \ , \ \ \ \ i=1,...,n+1 \ .
$$
The quotient defines the Lens space
$$
L_n(p)=S^{2n+1}/\mathbb{Z}_p \ .
$$
For instance $L_1(2)=\mathbb{RP}^3$. Let $A$ be an abelian group. The  homology groups with coefficients in $A$ are

$$
H_i(L_n(p),A)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
A & \text{if $i=0,2n+1$}\\
A/pA & \text{if $i$ is odd}\\
T_p(A) & \text{if $i$ is even}
\end{array} \right.
$$
where $T_p(A)\subset A$ is the $p-$torsion subgroup of $A$:
$$
T_p(A)=\left\{a\in A \ | \ pa=0 \ \right\}
$$
I would like to have the explicit representatives of the generators, in some simple cases. Specifically I would need the generators of:
$$
H_i(L_1(2),\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2 \ , \ i=1,2
$$
and $$
H_i(L_2(4),\mathbb{Z}_4)=\mathbb{Z}_4 \ , \ \ i=2,4 \ .
$$

In the first case, since $L_1(2)=\mathbb{RP}^3$, I think a very explicit description (to visualize them) of the these cycles should be possible. For the second case I would appreciate any kind of description.

Comment: For question 1, if you know the homology with integer coefficient, then you can determine homology with coefficients in any abelian group by universal coefficient theorem. For question 2, if you are working with cellular homology, then you can identify cycles with cells.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second point, for the two cases I listed?